# '+' in a URL parameter is replaced by a space

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url

I made an ajax request to rails. The URL is:

```
/learners/-638284588?is_combined_page=true&email=test0221k+staging@tt.com&type=ld"
```

In the log, I see these entries:

```
Started GET "/learners/-638284588?is_combined_page=true&    email=test0221k+staging@rosettastone.com&type=lcd" for 127.0.0.1 at Fri Feb 23 09:31:56 -0500 2018
Processing by Extranet::LearnersController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"type"=>"ld", "email"=>"test0221k staging@tt.com", "is_combined_page"=>"true", "id"=>"-638284588"}
[WARNING] Audit logging has been enabled for Account
parameter ----------------> {"type"=>"lcd", "email"=>"test0221k staging@tt.com", "controller"=>"extranet/learners", "is_combined_page"=>"true", "action"=>"show", "id"=>"-638284588"} test0221k staging@tt.com
```

In the URL, the `email` parameter appears as:

```
email="test0221k+staging@tt.com"
```

which has a `+` sign. But when I read the parameter from `params[:email]`, it is printed as:

```
"email"=>"test0221k staging@tt.com"
```

in which the `+` is replaced by a space.

Why does rails overwrite `+` with a space?
How can I avoid this `"test0221k staging@tt.com"` and get `"test0221k+staging@tt.com"`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is defined by the URL specification. Rails is just confirming to that spec.

Parameters need to be encoded before putting them in the URL. The easy way to do this is to call `encodeURIComponent()` in your JavaScript.

Forms do this encoding for you automatically.